# HttpWebResponse.GetResponse hangs in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have the following code:

```
string url = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}/xml",Address.Host,Address.Port,Address.ContextRoot);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.UserAgent = "Foo";
req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
req.KeepAlive = false;

using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    SoapEnvelope s = new SoapEnvelope(Address, null);
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = s.GenerateXml(message);
    xmlDoc.Save(reqStream);
}
result = ReceiveAnswer(req);


private string ReceiveAnswer(HttpWebRequest req)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    using (Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream))
    {

    if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("Failed to post data to http://{0}:{1}", Address.Host, Address.Port).AppendLine();
        sb.AppendFormat("Response: {0} {1}", res.StatusCode, res.StatusDescription);
        res.Close();
        throw new WebException(sb.ToString());
    }
    String resData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return resData;
    }
}
```

This code works fine, when I'm connecting to an existing server, but I've just tested, that if the server I specify does not exist then this part: (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse() will hang. I expected to get a webexception or something in this scenario, because I want to catch it.

I've read it somewhere that this Response has a timeout of 100 seconds, I've waited more than that, but nothing happened. Then I set the Timeout property to 15 seconds, but that didn't help either.

Anyone knows what should I do?

Comment: How come GetResponse() will hang when before it is GetRequestStream()? GetRequestStream() should throw timeout exception before GetResponse() when host is not responding...

Comment: I don't get this, GetrequestStream() is used to initialize a stream that can read the body of the response. I get this response from GetResponse() method. If the GetResponse hangs, this stream will not even be initialized. There is no way that GetRequestStream can throw an exception before GetResponse().

Comment: In your code example you are first calling GetRequestStream() and second GetResponseStream() which is in ReceiveAnswer() method. So invoke order is:
1. GetRequestStream()
2. GetResponseStream()

Comment: Ok, I get it, I've misread it, I'm sorry, I thought we are speaking of this: using (Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream()). But GetRequestStream does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: So, to sum things up. You are trying to connect to non-existing host and GetRequestStream() and whole using is not throwing any exception but after that GetResponse() hangs, right?

Comment: Exactly. I've tested it again, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with my code, an other part of the company's code causes the problem.

Comment: What other part if you wrote that you are connecting to non-existing host?

Comment: This whole thing is called in a Quartz-like self made class. That catches the exception, and does nothing with it.

Answer (score -1):

Be very careful with what you're doing.

```
    Timeout method does not apply to the time waiting for the response to be caught.
    Timeout counts for the entire life of your connection (meaning request + response).
```

If you're then setting a too-low timeout time, your program will never catch it. Maybe you could try to raise the Timeout number?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that, but the default value was 100 seconds, and the entire life of my connection is far less than that.

Comment: Yup, but if the response has a time out of 100 seconds, and you're setting the timeout property to 100, you're forgetting the requesting time.